# Executing filtered views from MSCRM db on client machine using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, view, dynamics-crm

I have ASP.NET application which runs on Internet. I want my application to Execute MSCRM Filtered Views on Client machine and return the values to My ASP.NET app where the result would be displayed.

Client (user) will provide his/her CRM Db credentials. So How do I achieve?

What are the details the user should provide for my application to connect to CRM? & How to execute the filtered views on his/her local machine?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Mayil

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695810.aspx) is described how to create connection to MS Dynamics CRM. But at first you should know what authentication type is used on CRM server. If it is IFD with claims-based authentication, you can find example [here](http://dynamicscrmdevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/07/ifd-claims-based-authentication.html)

```
Uri organizationUriIFD = new Uri("https://[server]:[port]/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");

ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
credentials.UserName.Password = "password";

IServiceConfiguration<IOrganizationService> config = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration<IOrganizationService>(organizationUriIFD);

using (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy _serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(config, credentials))
{
 // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
 _serviceProxy.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());

 IOrganizationService _service = (IOrganizationService)_serviceProxy;

 WhoAmIResponse response = (WhoAmIResponse)_service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest());
 Console.WriteLine(response.UserId.ToString());

 Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Next you will need Fetch XML, which represent filtered view. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928434.aspx) is example how to use Fetch XML.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I dont have Dynamic CRM developer tool. I download CRM SDK from online. I am uanble to use the above code. What are the namespace needs to be added? where it will be? CrmService class comes in which namespace?  Pls help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1199429 You should add references to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll and to  Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll and then resolve all dependencies.

Comment: paramosh, I am using Visual studio 2008, i am unable to add reference to Microsoft.xrm.sdk which was located in CRM2011 sdk. Help me,Any alternative way? I my application needs to access (over internet) client machine's CRM & fetch data based on filtered views from that machine and display the same in my application. thanks